# pivot_longer: passing "names_sep" as character yields different result than passing it as character index

Tags: r, dplyr

Say we have a data frame which looks something like

```
df <- data.frame(x_A = c(1, 2), x_B = c(3, 4), y_A = c(5, 6), y_B = c(7, 8))
df
  x_A x_B y_A y_B
1   1   3   5   7
2   2   4   6   8
```

Using `library(dplyr)` I'm wondering why passing `names_sep = "_"` in `pivot_longer` yields a different result than `names_sep = 2`, as seen in the following

```
pivot_longer(df, x_A:y_B, names_to = c("name1", "name2"), names_sep = "_")
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  name1 name2 value
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 x     A         1
2 x     B         3
3 y     A         5
4 y     B         7
5 x     A         2
6 x     B         4
7 y     A         6
8 y     B         8
```

```
pivot_longer(df, x_A:y_B, names_to = c("name1", "name2"), names_sep = 2)
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  name1 name2 value
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 x_    A         1
2 x_    B         3
3 y_    A         5
4 y_    B         7
5 x_    A         2
6 x_    B         4
7 y_    A         6
8 y_    B         8
```

When passing a string with the character to break on, that character itself is dropped. When passing the index of the character, it is not. Could someone explain why there is a difference?

Comment: It seems a decision of the programmers that `names_sep` work in such way.

Comment: For what it’s worth this is exactly the behaviour that I would intuitively expect, though I can see an argument for why one would expect a different behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the online doc:  "`names_sep` takes the same specification as `separate()`, and can either be a numeric vector (specifying positions to break on), or a single string (specifying a regular expression to split on)".

Note the difference in wording "split" for regular expression and "position to break" for numerics.  So with a regular expression, the split string is taken as a word separator (and not included in the output column names).  With a numeric, there is no "separator" and all characters in the original column name appear in the output.

As @KonradRudolph says, this is intuitive.  If you want the separator to appear in the output when using a regex, you have an inconsistency: does the separator get associated with the "name" to its left or to its right?  You can only resolve that by convention (which is sub-optimal) or an additional parameter (which - to me - is unnecessary and overly complicated).

Different results, but documented and intentional.  I wouldn't desribe the behaviour as inconsistent.